# ServletRegistrationBean and ControllerAdvice conflict in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets, spring-boot

I'm working with Spring boot 1.5.7. 
I hava a configuration class `DispatcherServletCustomConfiguration`  with a `ServletRegistrationBean`

```
ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(
               dispatcherServlet(), "/api/*");
```

In project exists another class with annotation @ControllerAdvice with 404 and error handler. The controller advice doesn't work.
If I disable `DispatcherServletCustomConfiguration` the controller advice works correctly.
Can you help me please? Bye.

UPDATE:

Controller Advice:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleNoHandlerFoundException(NoHandlerFoundException ex, HttpHeaders headers,
            HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        GenericResponse response = new GenericResponse();
        response.getStatus().setCodice(EsitiMapping.NOT_FOUND.getEsito());
        response.getStatus().setDescrizione(EsitiMapping.NOT_FOUND.getDescrizioneEsito());
        response.getStatus().setCodice(EsitiMapping.NOT_FOUND.getCodice());
        //log.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
        return handleExceptionInternal(ex, response, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, request);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(value = { Exception.class })
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleGenericError(RuntimeException ex, WebRequest request) {
        GenericResponse response = new GenericResponse();
        response.getStatus().setCodice(EsitiMapping.INTERNAL_ERROR.getEsito());
        response.getStatus().setDescrizione(EsitiMapping.INTERNAL_ERROR.getDescrizioneEsito());
        response.getStatus().setCodice(EsitiMapping.INTERNAL_ERROR.getCodice());
        log.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
        return handleExceptionInternal(ex, response, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, request);
    }

}
```

Servlet Registration Bean:

```
@Configuration
public class DispatcherServletCustomConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet() {
        return new DispatcherServlet();
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean dispatcherServletRegistration() {
        ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(
                dispatcherServlet(), "/api/*");
        registration.setName(DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.DEFAULT_DISPATCHER_SERVLET_REGISTRATION_BEAN_NAME);
        return registration;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please paste your full config.

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna I updated the post. Thank you

Comment: Did you have any class that extends `WebApplicationInitializer` ? If you have, then paste that config.

Comment: I have a simple @SpringBootApplication application class.

Comment: Please annotate your `RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler` class with `@EnableWebMvc` and let me know the status.

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna I have ever same status.

Comment: you're getting a 404 for which request? could you add the request/response header information in your question?

Comment: Nothing, the advice doesn't works.

Comment: I want manage the not found error (404) with controller advice, but it has a conflict with DispatcherServletCustomConfiguration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean dispatcherServletRegistration() {
    ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(
            dispatcherServlet(), "/api/*");
    dispatcherServlet().setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound(true);
    registration.setName(DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.DEFAULT_DISPATCHER_SERVLET_REGISTRATION_BEAN_NAME);
    return registration;
}
```

I set `dispatcherServlet().setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound(true);` to handle with advice the not found error.